# MEF Import doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, mef

I have two classes with exports:

```
[Export(typeof(Mod))]
public class CoreMod : Mod
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CoreMod()
    {
      //here goes my constructor
    }
}

[Export(typeof(Mod))]
public class AnotherMod : Mod
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public AnotherMod()
    {
      //here goes my constructor
    }
}
```

`CoreMod` is in my main assembly, `AnotherMod` is in the external assembly. `Mod` is in yet another assembly, which they are both referencing.
In my app I have a class which tries to load Mods via MEF:

```
class ModManager
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(Mod))]
    public static IEnumerable<Mod> Mods { get; set; }

    public List<Mod> LoadedMods { get; set; } 

    public ModManager()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(CoreMod).Assembly));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .CodeBase).LocalPath)));

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        LoadedMods = Mods.ToList();
    }
}
```

Looks to me like all imports should be satisfied, but it still fails to import anything (`Mods` is null). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the title of your question should be 'MEF import doesn't work **as expected**'. I'm pretty sure MEF as a whole is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you have your `CompositionContainer` as a function variable instead of a class variable. Also, MEF does not support importing to a static variable. Try using this:

```
class ModManager
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(Mod))]
    public IEnumerable<Mod> Mods { get; set; }

    public List<Mod> LoadedMods { get; set; } 
    CompositionContainer _container;

    public ModManager()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(CoreMod).Assembly));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .CodeBase).LocalPath)));

        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        this._container.ComposeParts(this);

        this.LoadedMods = this.Mods.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the whole problem was in `static` keyword. Strange, but the example I've studied before writing my code was using static collection. Maybe older version of MEF.

Comment: Did everything as in answer, it doesn't work for me, IEnumerable is null every time.